# (Java) Variable names must match pattern?

Tags: java, variables, naming-conventions, conventions

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComparingNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int FirstNum = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        int SecondNum = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

        if (FirstNum > SecondNum) {

            System.out.println(FirstNum + " is greater than " + SecondNum + ".");
        } else if (FirstNum < SecondNum) {
            System.out.println(FirstNum + " is smaller than " + SecondNum + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println(FirstNum + " is equal to " + SecondNum + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Line 9:    Name 'FirstNum' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.

Line 10:   Name 'SecondNum' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.

What is the issue with my variable names?. I am a beginner so a simple answer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Java variable names should be camelCase. Variable names should be **firstNum** and **secondNum**.